# Rails Observer Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observer-pattern, rails-activerecord

I am trying to use observers in my rails app to create a new entry in my "Events" Model every time a new "Comment" is saved. The comments are saving fine, but the observer is not creating events properly.

```
// comment_observer.rb
class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :comment

  def after_save(comment)
    event = comment.user.events.create
    event.kind = "comment"
    event.data = { "comment_message" => "#{comment.message}" }
    event.save!
  end
```

This observer works great I use it in the console but it doesn't seem to be observing properly; when I try my app it just doesn't seem to create events. I don't see errors or anything.

Also I have  `config.active_record.observers = :comment_observer` in my environment.rb file.

Where am I going wrong? Should I be taking a different approach?

Comment: i just ended up putting this logic in the comment_controller.rb create action.  Am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: I have the same issues, except it's happening with some models and not others. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the the **observe** statement since your class is named CommentObserver.

Try leaving it out.

Or try:

```
observe Comment
```

instead of

```
observe :comment
```

Answer (score 25):

Indeed, you need `observe :comment` only if comment class can’t be inferred from the observer name (i.e., is not called CommentObserver).

Did you declare your observer in application.rb:

```
# Activate observers that should always be running
config.active_record.observers = :comment_observer
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart the server

Comment: Correct, you need to declare the observer in application.rb, which is slightly annoying.